# Retrofit get single string best practiece

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I need to get a lot of jsons like: `{"data":"ok"}`, `{"key":"..."}` and etc.

Which is better, create kotlin `data class` to each response and get

```
@GET("...")
suspend fun getData1(): AnyResponse1

@GET("...")
suspend fun getData2(): AnyResponse2
```

or use map:

```
@GET("...")
suspend fun getData1(): Map<String, String>

@GET("...")
suspend fun getData2(): Map<String, String>
```

(I'm using `GsonConverterFactory`)

Same question to send objects like above

```
@POST("...")
suspend fun getData1(@Body req: AnyRequest1): AnyResponse1

@POST("...")
suspend fun getData2(@Body req: AnyRequest2): AnyResponse2
```

or

```
@POST("...")
suspend fun getData1(@Body map: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String>

@POST("...")
suspend fun getData2(@Body map: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String>
```

Comment: I think it's better to use DTO design pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object So use data classes

Comment: I Suggest to Use `data class` since you will know which class is mapped to which response.